# Typesafe config: get as map

Tags: scala, typesafe

```
googlesheets{
 dmkb_sheet = "1xEC8CPlKn654321wcoS_JB12345cPPiaA0M"
 other_sheet = "123isS0M30TH3R1D"
}
```

I would like to use something like `myConfig.getAsMap("googlesheets")` and get the two nested entries as a Map. No such method exists. So what is the easiest way to load the two nested entries as a Map?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some definition of easy you could use something like this:

```
val config = conf.atKey("googlesheets")
config.root.keySet.asScala.map(key ⇒ key → config.getString(key)).toMap
```

I would argue that it would be even easier to use a library for mapping configurations to case classes, like [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig)

Comment: better answer than mine.Thanks'

Answer (score 6):

OK, that was easy.

`myConfig.getConfig("googlesheets").entrySet()` does the trick

(I was fixated on the method having a "get" prefix, so missed it)

Answer (score 3):

I was after a scala `Map[String, String]` @Senthil's answer came closest to what I was after but the Map values were quoted i.e. they were enclosed in double quotes and that caused a nasty bug which was not easy to spot. The way I was able to resolve it is by doing `configValue.unwrapped().toString()` rather than `configValue.render()`

Before this I tried `render()` with various `ConfigRenderOptions` but I did not get the desired result

```
config
    .getConfig("<key>")
    .entrySet()
    .asScala
    .map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.unwrapped().toString)
    .toMap
```

I am using this in scala and therefore convert it to scala type

Alas, typesafe config which is otherwise a cool library had to make config as Map so hard!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I got it working by re-writing your answer as follows:

```
config.entrySet().asScala.map(e => e.getKey -> e.getValue.render()).toMap
```

Comment: This approach does not work when using quotes. 
For example: bootstrap.servers = "localhost:9092" will not work properly

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking to read the whole config as `Map[String, Any]` then the following can be achieved with following recursion.

```scala
def configAsMap(config: Config): Map[String, Any] = {
  config
    .entrySet()
    .asScala
    .map { entry =>
      entry.getKey -> unwrappedValue(entry.getValue)
    }
    .toMap
}

def unwrappedValue(value: ConfigValue): Any = value match {
  case l: ConfigList   => l.asScala.map(cv => unwrappedValue(cv))
  case o: ConfigObject => configAsMap(o.toConfig)
  case v               => v.unwrapped()
}
```

It will load config lists into Scala `Seq` and config objects as `Map[String, ?]`. This is useful if one has config structures as following

```
foo = []
foo += {bar: Bar}
foo += {zoo: Zoo}
```